# Laravel query to list results

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to write a query which takes a collection of records and loops through them and displays them all but i need it to hide a specific record if one record contains a field as true.

**Use Case**

1. Grab collection of products where the `purchased` field is true
2. if a product from the collection has the field `includes_bonus` set to true list ALL products apart from the `bonus` product which has the id of 2

**1.**

This grabs all the products that have purchased set to true

```
$productsPurchased = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1)->get();
```

**2 attempt**

Below i trying to do the above but im not having much luck.

1. Grab all products with purchased set to 1(true)
2. if product `includes_bonus` as 1(true) hide product record with id of 2 from list of products.

   ```
   $productsPurchased = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1)
       ->where('includes_bonus', 1)
       ->where('products.id', '!==', 2)
       ->get();
   ```

**blade**

I then wanna do a foreach within the blade which lists all the products with my use case.

```
   @foreach($purchasedProducts as $purchasedProduct)
                <div class="col-xl-6 p-0 p-xl-4 mb-5 mb-xl-0">
                        <div class="card border">
                            <div class="card-header border rounded-top"
                               </div>
                            <div class="card-block">
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'filter' collection

```
$productsPurchased->filter(function ($value, $key) {
return '**condition for filter**';
```

});

Comment: How would i adjust the syntax within the return condition to match what i need?

Comment: $productsPurchased->filter(function($value) {
    return !empty($value);
})

the filter itself removes the empty value, I just right it for reference.

Comment: show your response and what u what u want to remove from that response.

Comment: i want to do if($productPurchased->includes_bonus) { // filter out product e.g (`benefits.id`, !=, 2) }

Comment: I basically just want to grab the collection and if a record has `includes_bonus` as true then remove `product` 2 from the collection

Comment: check the doc you get clarification with the syntax:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter

I hope this will help u

Comment: where would i place the IF statement? can you update your answer it will be easier to see please

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
      $productsPurchased = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1);

      if($user->products()->where('includes_bonus', 1)->first()){
            $productsPurchased=$productsPurchased->where('products.id', '!=', 2);
      }

      $productsPurchased=$productsPurchased->get();
```

Comment: $productsPurchased=$productsPurchased isn't correct syntax do you mind modifying your answer?

Comment: It is ```$productsPurchased=$productsPurchased->get();``` not ```$productsPurchased=$productsPurchased``` and it is ok I used this before